# Name given to save/open 'slide out menus/views' in cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface

What is the name given to these windows/views that sort of slide down from the toolbar? Like the new file one in Xcode or the save as dialog in text edit.

(i can't post pictures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called Sheets

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/sheets/sheets.html

Comment: if you feel I answered your question, click that 'tick' button

Comment: Thanks! I just thought you mightn't realise as you were new.